# How do I determine if a table exists in a SQL Server database in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How do I determine if a table exists in a SQL Server database in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you query the sysobjects table, with a query like

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'U' AND name = 'yourTableName'
```

xtype = 'U' is a user table

you can then wrap this is an IF EXISTS statement

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects ...)
BEGIN
    ' do your stuff here if it exists
END
```

Comment: +1 It is important to note that Microsoft has been moving functionality like this to Dynamic Management Views (DMVs) since SQL Server 2005.  This will technically work, but Microsoft now recommends using the sys.tables DMV for this.  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE type = 'U' AND name = 'yourTableName').  Functionally, your statement and my statement do the exact same thing.  Just wanted to mention DMVs.  To learn more about DMVs, check out the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188754%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx

Comment: That's a good call Matt. Old habits die hard :-) Yours is the better way.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes much difference but I'd favour IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables...)

Comment: @DavidHayes Yes, I guess this solution is faster because it does not query to find column names.

Answer (score 12):

Here is one more way of finding it

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tablename') IS NULL
PRINT 'Table Does not Exist'
```

Comment: Nice and simple, no need to query complex system tables. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't that detect, for example, views of the same name? Perhaps stored procedures and such as well?

Comment: Not if you schema qualify the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your table name here')
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Table Exists'
END
```